# filter json results based on value with url

Tags: php, mysql, json, filter

I am running a Mysql query in a php file and parsing it as json as follow:

```
$json_response = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['artist'] = $row['artist'];
    $row_array['song'] = $row['song'];

    //push the values in the array
    array_push($json_response,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($json_response);
```

There are thousands of entries; Is there any way I can filter the JSON results based on a value? 
something like: mylink.php/artist1 or mylink.php?artist=1

I would really appreciate any sort of ideas.

thanks

Comment: What is your MySQL query (SELECT statement), and is this for a website?  How does a user interact with this code?

Comment: Well, the reason I am doing this is because there are hundreds of artists that each time one will be accessed to return their songs.. And yes it is for a website but later on it will be accessed in an ios app the retreive the necessary info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it so:

```
// Get artist info
$artist_id = isset($_GET['artist']) ? intval($_GET['artist']) : 0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM artist";
if($artist_id)
    $sql .= " WHERE artist=$artist_id";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you should filter the result with your SQL, not with PHP...

Try to Google for "MySQL SELECT FROM WHERE" it will easily help you

Answer (score 0):

First, the MySQL API you are using is deprecated and will eventually be removed.  It is recommended you switch to [MySQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) for any new development.

In PHP to get URL parameters user the [$_GET superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

```
$artist = $_GET['artist'];
```

You must then bind the paramter to your SELECT statement.  Here is why it would be best to switch to MySQLI or PDO because the mysql_* functions in PHP do not support prepared statements and parameterized queries.  Read more at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

That said, using mysql_* here is a way to pass the artist into your query:

```
// Query
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE artist='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($artist));

$result = mysql_query($query);


$json_response = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['artist'] = $row['artist'];
    $row_array['song'] = $row['song'];

    //push the values in the array
    array_push($json_response,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($json_response);
```